# double sum in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sum, binomial-coefficients

I would like to write a Matlab code to calculate the following:

\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{i=0}^{k} {k \choose i}(a-1)^{k-i} a^k

and my code is:

```
N = 3;
a = [3 4];
for k = 0:N-1
    f = 0;
     for i = 0:k
         f = f + nchoosek(k,i).* a.^k .* (a-1).^(k-i);  
     end
     sumoff = sum(f);
     all = (( 1./ (factorial(k))).*sumoff);
end
overall= sum(all);
```

'all' variable gives different value when it is inside the for loop rather than outside. But I want it to calculate when k = 0:N-1. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your current code overwrites `all` on every iteration. Moving it outside the loop also doesn't work because you'll only save the result of the last iteration.

To save the `all` of every iteration, define `all` as a vector and then assign each intermediate result into that vector:

```matlab
N = 3;
a = [3 4];

% preallocate a vector for `all`
all = nan(N-1, 1);

for k = 0:N-1
    f = 0;
    for i = 0:k
        f = f + nchoosek(k,i) .* a.^k .* (a-1).^(k-i);  
    end
    sumoff = sum(f);
    
    % assign your intermediate result into the `all` vector
    all(k+1) = ((1./(factorial(k))) .* sumoff);
end
overall = sum(all);
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you.